# Angular 6 IE style inline

Tags: html, css, angular

I got this perfectly inline horizontal divs rendererd in a row:

```
  <div class="row"  ng-style="{'display': 'inline-flex'}"   *ngIf="resgeceived"> 
     <div ng-style="{'display': 'inline-flex'}"   class="col-md-24 col-sm-24">
        <div [hidden]="show != _NUCBBBIESTE">
           <pcgfdgo [ricBBBste]="nuovBBBeste"></pcgfdgo>
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="show != _RIDDDO "></div> 
     </div>
  </div>
```

In IE I've tried those `ng-style` to make them aligned horizontally and tried thousands of other ways without luck.

I got nothing inside the **.scss.**

What's the correct approach to make IE look like Chrome rendering?

Comment: would you please provide a live example?

Comment: Upgrade it to 10? https://caniuse.com/#search=Inline-flex

Comment: It's `[ngStyle]`, not `ng-style` in Angular 2+. [ngStyle](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngStyle). That being said, given you aren't resolving dynamic values, you can just use `style`.

Comment: already tried style="{'display': 'inline-flex'}" , that works via IE devtool but not applied in ng-content div inside the page

Comment: Why add them inline?

Comment: It's an attempt. In chrome it works, in ie won't so I've tried that style to force in IE.

Comment: Not style="{'display': 'inline-flex'}", but [ngStyle]="{'display': 'inline-flex'}"

Answer (score 0):

it should be **-ms-inline-flexbox** you can add some mixins to support old browsers and ie, example for inline-flex

```
@mixin inline-flex {
   display: -webkit-inline-box; // ios
   display: -moz-inline-box;
   display: -webkit-inline-flex;
   display: -ms-inline-flexbox; // for IE
   display: inline-flex;
}

%inline-flex { @include inline-flex; }
```

Comment: is this supposed to be in the scss? it doesn't affect the page at all....